# How to block access to Tomcat listening port, and allow localhost only?

Tags: tomcat, access-control

I have an application running on Tomcat and listening on port 8080. I made the redirect changes on the Apache level (httpd) to provide my users with the ability to only type `http://app` instead of `http://app:8080`.

Now I want to **block** access completely to `http://app:8080`, so users won't be able to reach `http://app:8080`.

How do I do that?

Comment: This sounds contradictory to me, if 8080 is indeed the public-facing port. Do you mean to have the users connect to your application via normal port (80), while redirecting 80 to 8080 internally?

Comment: Yes. I don't want 8080 to be exposed at all.

Comment: ok, this is probably a serverfault question then, similar to something like: http://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can block a port using `iptables`, which is quite secure considering it's on OS level:

```
iptables -A INPUT/ -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP
```

Or you can comment the 8080 connector in `tomcat`’s configuration (in `server.xml`):

```
<!--
<Connector port="8080" …
    />
-->
```

Or you can just limit access to localhost (in case you want to use the manager app, etc.):

```
<Connector port="8080" address="127.0.0.1" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" />
```

(don’t forget to restart `tomcat` afterwards).

Comment: Thank you Will, that attribute to the tomcat Connector did the trick. Together with Apache's ProxyPass directive that gives a decent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness you might want to configure the AJP Connector in a similar way or disable it in server.xml