# How to avoid application access using IP in network?

Tags: java, ip

I have application named `MailSys`. When I run it's login page it's url is something like this :

```
http://localhost:8080/MailSys/login.jsp
```

This application is on my computer. But my PC is connected to network, so anyone can access my application using my IP like:

```
192.168.0.18:8080/MailSys/login.jsp
```

So is there any way to avoid this access to my application? I am developing application in JAVA using Eclipse.

Comment: Operating system firewall? Or deny non-local IPs

Comment: @AlexK. - How to deny non-local IPs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, block port 8080 on your firewall. Or even better do it at the router level.

If your on windows, you can go to the windows firewall in control panel and go to advanced setting, where you can set a rule, to block port 8080 incoming.

Comment: 8080 port will work after blocking ? Means in my local system ?

Comment: yes, it will work on your local system. But it will block external requests to that port and so it will not serve the application when someone requests to view it over the network.

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables -A INPUT/ -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP
```

You can blocking a port using Iptables,

Which is quite secured consider it's on OS level,

or you can modify tomcat config,

```
<Connector port="8080" address="127.0.0.1" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
```

to only allow localhost access 8080, (in case you want to use the manager app etc)

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809968/how-to-block-access-to-tomcat-listening-port-and-allow-localhost-only)

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses is used to access to computers in IP networks. so if you want to provide public access to your application you can't restrict access to is using only domain names. If you are going to restrict access to your application during development and allow access only for yourself you need ether configure firewall to restrict access to 8080 port of your computer, or configure your servlet container to listen only local host IP address 127.0.0.1 for i.e. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617/how-do-you-configure-tomcat-to-bind-to-a-single-ip-address-localhost-instead-o)