# How to block public access to tomcat and solr interfaces

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr, tomcat7, sunspot-rails

I'm using Solr in my rails app and I would like to know how to disable access completely to the public web interface for tomcat and solr. I'm using CentOS.

i.e., the following urls should yield timeouts:

```
http://mydomain.com:8080/ # Tomcat7
http://mydomain.com/solr/* # Solr
```

I just don't see a reason to have them publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is more related to the Tomcat server.

You can find a particular solution here [Tomcat localhost access only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809968/how-to-block-access-to-tomcat-listening-port-and-allow-localhost-only).